# Consider the region R bounded by $y = \sin x $ and $y$ =$\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}$. Find the area of R.

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider the region R bounded by $y = \sin x $  and $y$ =$\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}$. Find the area of R.

**My attempt**

$$\sin x=\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}$$

$$\pi^2\sin x=4x^2$$

$$4x^2-\pi^2\sin x=0$$

But, I am struck here. Can anyone please help to find the area

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The region bounded by the graphs of these functions has an area equal to$$\int_0^{\frac\pi2}\sin(x)-\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}\,\mathrm dx.$$Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sir, can you please tell how did you get $\int_0^{\frac\pi2}$

Comment: @tienlee at $0$, both $\sin(x)$ and $\frac{4x^2}{\pi^2}$ are $0$. And at $\frac\pi2$ they are both equal to $1$.

Comment: So, the integral representing the volume obtained by rotating
the region R about the x-axis will be  $\int _{ 0 }^{ \Pi /2 }{ \Pi  } ((sinx)^ 2-(\frac { 4x^ 2 }{ \Pi ^ 2 } )^2)$

Comment: @tienlee That's another question. Please post it as such.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The Solutions are given by $x=0$ or $x=\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: So, the integral representing the volume obtained by rotating
the region R about the x-axis will be  $\int _{ 0 }^{ \Pi /2 }{ \Pi  } ((sinx)^ 2-(\frac { 4x^ 2 }{ \Pi ^ 2 } )^2)$